# Speed of light and virtual particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, speed-of-light, visible-light, refraction, virtual-particles

After becoming extremely bored while studying for an Afrikaans exam, I started thinking about [virtual particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle). So, can light (photons) interact with virtual particles (even though they only exist for a very short time)? And can these virtual particles "slow down" light in the same way as atoms delay light when travelling through a medium?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, light can interact with "virtual particles".  It can also interact with itself via virtual particle interactions (see [Delbruck Scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delbruck_scattering)), although I believe direct observation of this effect is currently outside of our experimental capability.

Edit: Just realised I didn't address the second part.  When a photon propagates, the propagation receives contributions from its splitting into an electron-positron pair which recombine etc.  These processes contribute corrections to the photon propagator, but they do so in such a way that the propagator pole remains in the same place, which in turn means that the propagation speed is unaffected.

Comment: Direct observation *is* within experimental capability.  See "Measurement of the Magnetically Induced QED Birefringence of the Vacuum and an Improved Laboratory Search for Axions" by Siu Au Lee, William M Fairbank Jr, and Walter Toki (Colorado State Univ) - Fermilab proposal, 1995 (that was a while ago!)